# Spark: Reading data from XML/Parquet/Sequence files

Tags: xml, apache-spark, hive, hue, parquet

I'm new to Spark, and am currently working mostly with Hive & Impala on  a cloudera HDFS cluster.

I have a dozens of XML files which I've used to create an external table from using Hive.

The table is currently stored as a Parquet file.

Now, I want to read this data using Spark..
Can I read data straight from the table?

Or do I have to read it from the raw data?
If so, is there a performance difference between the different formats
(XML, Sequence, Parquet)?

Thank you.

Update:
Our hive cluster currently works on a Spark engine.
However, I'm talking about writing actual Spark code in Scala, and having it read Hive tables / XMLs / Sequence Files / Parquet Files.

Comment: [Hive can run on Spark](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark%3A+Getting+Started)

Comment: Thank you @RemusRusanu, but I'm actually talking about actual Spark code (that I intend to write in Scala).

I've updated the question appropriately.

Comment: Using Spark-sql you can directly read data from Hive tables persisted in HDFS - http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables

Comment: That might just work! Thank you :)

Comment: [Spark-Parquet](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#parquet-files)